# java/processing return ArrayList throws: This method must return a result of Type ArrayList

Tags: java, processing

I have this function `makeAirportManagers()` which should return an `ArrayList <MarkerManager>` all required variables `map, countryMarkers` and `airportMarkers` are global (dirty processing style).

```
ArrayList  makeAirportManagers(){
  ArrayList  managers = new ArrayList();
  for (Marker country : countryMarkers){
    MarkerManager currentMarkerManager = new MarkerManager();
    for (Marker airport : airportMarkers){
      Location airportLocation = airport.getLocation();
      ScreenPosition airportScreenPos = map.getScreenPosition(airportLocation);
      if(country.isInside(map, airportScreenPos.x, airportScreenPos.y)){
        currentMarkerManager.addMarker(airport);
      }
    }
    currentMarkerManager.disableDrawing();
    managers.add(currentMarkerManager);
    map.addMarkerManager(currentMarkerManager);
    airportManagersBuild = true;
    return managers;
  }
}
```

The console prints: This method must return a result of Type ArrayList

And really I don't no why!

In another version of the code, I count the items of `managers`to make sure it`s not empty and it gets 178 items like expected.

I am using Processing 1.5.1 because of the Unfolding library I'm playing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` method is inside the `for` loop. You must move it one line below.

Comment: I am so blind! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If countryMarkers has no element in it, you will never reach the line `return managers` and your method won't return anything.

Even if you know that your container will never be empty, the Java compiler does not. Thus your error.

Comment: Thank you, but `countryMarkers` is not empty.

Comment: You know that. Not your compiler. Your compiler is righter than you or me